# download sony add on android sdk via command line

Tags: android, continuous-integration, sony, android-sdk-tools

I have an android app that is built using the sony add on sdk. I would like build my app in ci. Is there is a way to download the sdk via command line.

Because the sdk is not available on the default google site. So I was wondering if I can add a  Add On site to android sdk via command line and download the sdk. Because I can't create a CI agent preinstalled with the sdk as I use the travis hosted ci and don't have much control over it.

Can someone help me..??

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Check your SDK into SCM (SCM being svn, git, tfs, perforce, whatever)
- Use a pre-task to use wget/curl to fetch your SDK into your CI servers project workspace and move along from there.

(Dunno what Travis hosted CI is.) I looked it up, and it looks like some cloud based rails-like CI. I suggest you use Jenkins/Hudson/TeamCity/Bamboo or even TFS locally.

Comment: would I not violate any copyrights by checking in the third party binaries in a repo of my own?

Comment: I am not a lawyer. If your repository is private, this is likely acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For my own gradle-builded projects I've made a [binary repo](https://github.com/goncharov/smart-extension-api) on GitHub and use it in TeamCity and BuildHive (Jenkins) CIs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above suggestions, this is how I'm doing it right now,

Created an SVN repo(I used Google SVN), and checkedin the required zip jar file.

So on the build agent, use wget to download the file from the SVN repo, extract it, copy the contents into android sdk/addons folder (as this an Add on SDK). And then was able to successfully compile my android project using the Sony Add-on SDK.